# When to use SVDRecommender

Tags: mahout, svd

I compared SVDRecommender with UserBasedRecommender and found the result of  usedBasedRecommender is much better than SVD in scare dataset. How to explain it ?

Comment: Did you find any answer for such question?

Answer (score 1):

SVD recommender "factorizes" initial user-to-item relationship into intermediate set of "features". This means that in theory recommendation should be more accurate because it is based on information extracted from the whole dataset (in constract to UserBasedRecommender that usually creates recommendation list from the limited number of "neighborhoods").

SVD recommender highly depends on "quality" of factorization and typical implementations have some control parameters that should be adopted for concrete dataset.